# Find last element in dynamically changing xpath

Tags: xpath, ui-automation

```xml
//div[text()='abc']
```

It gives sometime 10 count, next time 20 and so on.

How can I find the last element in count even if the count changes dynamically?

Comment: Hi there, I added the `xpath` tag and simplified the title so that users who might know the answer can find your question more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. You have to use `last()` xpath function to return a number equal to context size of the expression evaluation context, meaning it will get the size of the matching elements and you can access the last item by using the below standard xpath notation.

Rather specifying `[1]` or `[5]` you are passing the last item number.

```
(//yourxpath)[last()]
```

In your case the xpath will be

```
(//div[text()='abc'])[last()]
```

Here is the link with more explation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256083(v%3Dvs.100)